# dataTables bStateSave local storage multiple tables on a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I have a Rails app using dataTables.  In order to have multiple tables on the same page, I have several IDs. This works fine except the bStateSave doesn't work.  bStateSave works fine on the pages with just one dataTable.

Here is my code:

```
  $("#dataTable0").dataTable
    bStateSave: true
    bStateDuration: 0
    fnStateSave: (oSettings, oData) ->
      localStorage.setItem "DataTables_" + window.location.pathname, JSON.stringify(oData)
    fnStateLoad: (oSettings) ->
      JSON.parse localStorage.getItem("DataTables_" + window.location.pathname)
    ....

  $("#dataTable1").dataTable(
    bStateSave: true
    bStateDuration: 0
    fnStateSave: (oSettings, oData) ->
      localStorage.setItem "DataTables_" + window.location.pathname, JSON.stringify(oData)
    fnStateLoad: (oSettings) ->
      JSON.parse localStorage.getItem("DataTables_" + window.location.pathname)
    ...
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you seen this? [https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/14248/bstatesave-for-multiple-tables/p1](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/14248/bstatesave-for-multiple-tables/p1)

Comment: I did read that posting.  But, it really doesn't address my issue.  But, I think I've figured out my own answer.  I've added  `+ "-" + 0` in the first dataTable localStorage name and  `+ "-" + 1` in the second.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes:

```
  $("#dataTable0").dataTable
    bStateSave: true
    bStateDuration: 0
    fnStateSave: (oSettings, oData) ->
      localStorage.setItem "DataTables_" + window.location.pathname + "-" + 0, JSON.stringify(oData)
    fnStateLoad: (oSettings) ->
      JSON.parse localStorage.getItem("DataTables_" + window.location.pathname + "-" + 0)

$("#dataTable1").dataTable
    bStateSave: true
    bStateDuration: 0
    fnStateSave: (oSettings, oData) ->
      localStorage.setItem "DataTables_" + window.location.pathname + "-" + 1, JSON.stringify(oData)
    fnStateLoad: (oSettings) ->
      JSON.parse localStorage.getItem("DataTables_" + window.location.pathname + "-" + 1)
```